# How to create map with random numbers inside in c

Tags: c, loops, random

I have task about printing board where you should input dimension and program will create a board with 2 numbers inside each cell: 1'st number is random from 1-3 and second one should be zero. I can make it only with zero but when i tried to make a random number everything went wrong way..
Maybe anyone knowns what it wrong with it?

Function calls uploading map:

```
int randfunc(int i, int n);

int uploadmap(int m,int n){
    int a[m][n];
    int i,j,k;
    // time_t t;
    //srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    //int randnum =  rand() % 3 + 1;
    for(i = 0; i < m;i++){
        printf("+---");

    }
    printf("+\n");
    memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
    for(i = 0;i < m;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n;j++){
            printf("|%d %d",randfunc(i,n),a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
        for(k = 0;k < m;k++){
            printf("+---");

        }
        printf("+\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

function which calls random numbers from 1 to 3:

```
int randfunc(int i, int n) {

    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        printf("%d\n", rand() % 3 + 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Main function :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int m,n;
    printf("Enter dimension: \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&m, &n);
    printf("Map has been uploaded %d\n",uploadmap(m,n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should call `srand` only once, e.g. in `main`. Your `randfunc` does not return any useful value. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: There is no use in passing `i` as a parameter to `randfunc`. Why do you do that?

Comment: _when i tried to make a random number everything went wrong way_ This is a bit unspecific. I assume after involving `randfunc()` your nice board isn't printed nice anymore? Please, consider that your `randfunc()` has a side effect - it prints itself: `printf("%d\n", rand() % 3 + 1);`. Wouldn't it be better to return the value instead of printing it? (And what is the loop good for?)

Comment: Well, the aim is to write a game called "Hey, that's mine fish". Creating a board explains in this way: "row 1 (board dimension): m n
rows 2 to m+1: n fields separated by single spaces, each field consists of 2 digits: first digit represents
number of fish (0-3), second digit represents player’s number (1 to at most 9 players, or 0 if the tile is unoccupied). A combination of numbers 00 represents the grid field without the ice floe. In his turn the player modifies the field of departure and field of arrival.

Comment: Replace `printf("|%d %d",randfunc(i,n),a[i][j]);` with `printf("|%d 0",(rand()%3)+1);`

Comment: You are printing the return value of your `randfunc` function ... but `randfunc` always returns 0.

Comment: `randfunc` does not do what you seem to think it does.  You seem to think it generates a random number from `i+1` to `n` .  What it actually does is generate (and print and discard) `n` random numbers from 1 to 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following simple `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void uploadmap(int m,int n) {
    for (int i = 0;i < m; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            printf("|%d 0", (rand() % 3)+1);
        printf("|\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int m, n;
    printf("Enter dimension: \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&m, &n);
    uploadmap(m,n);

    return 0;
}
```